# Visual Studio not showing warnings when there are no errors (C++)

Tags: c, visual-studio, gcc, makefile, visual-studio-2019

I finally figured out how to configure remote linux debugging (gcc, gdb, makefile project) in VS2019 but I still have a problem: whenever I build my solution without errors, the "Error list" is not populated at all, despite evident gcc Warnings in the "Output" window. This problem does not occour when the code contains errors, in which case both errors and warnings are correctly displayed.

Test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int a = 0;
    printf("Hello Linux!\n");
    a = fun();
    return 0;
}

int fun() {
    return 0;
}
```

Makefile:

```
all: myprog.c 
    gcc -g -Wall -o myprog myprog.c

clean: 
    $(RM) myprog
```

Visual Studio "Output" window:

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: Project2, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Build started 04/12/2020 18:00:26.
1>Target _ValidateSources:
1>  Validating sources
1>Target _CopySources:
1>  Copying sources remotely to 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'
1>  Copying file 'C:\Users\abc\source\repos\Project2\Project2\myprog.c' to '/home/abc/projects/Project2/myprog.c'
1>  Skipping 'C:\Users\abc\source\repos\Project2\Project2\Makefile', as it is up to date.
1>Target Build:
1>  Target _Build_Common:
1>    Target _Clean_BuildUpToDate:
1>      Deleting file "C:\Users\abc\source\repos\Project2\Project2\obj\x64\Debug\Project2.builduptodate".
1>    Build command not configured, skipping.
1>    Invoking 'make', working directory: '/home/abc/projects/Project2/'
1>    gcc -g -Wall -o myprog myprog.c
1>    myprog.c: In function ‘main’:
1>    myprog.c:7:6: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘fun’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
1>      a = fun();
1>          ^~~
1>    myprog.c:5:6: warning: variable ‘a’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
1>      int a = 0;
1>          ^
1>    Copying file '/home/abc/projects/Project2/myprog' to 'C:\Users\abc\source\repos\Project2\Project2\bin\x64\Debug\myprog'
1>
1>Build succeeded.
1>    0 Warning(s)
1>    0 Error(s)
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.14
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Suggestions? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
An example of (WORKING) "Output" building a program that contains errors (these warnings are correctly parsed by VS):

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: Project2, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Build started 04/12/2020 21:50:23.
1>Target _ValidateSources:
1>  Validating sources
1>Target _CopySources:
1>  Copying sources remotely to 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'
1>  Copying file 'C:\Users\abc\source\repos\Project2\Project2\myprog.c' to '/home/abc/projects/Project2/myprog.c'
1>  Skipping 'C:\Users\abc\source\repos\Project2\Project2\Makefile', as it is up to date.
1>Target Build:
1>  Target _Build_Common:
1>    Build command not configured, skipping.
1>    Invoking 'make', working directory: '/home/abc/projects/Project2/'
1>    myprog.c(5,12): error : unknown type name ‘hahaha’
1>    myprog.c(6,9): error : expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before string constant
1>    myprog.c(7,6): warning : implicit declaration of function ‘fun’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
1>    myprog.c(5,6): warning : variable ‘a’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
1>    gcc -g -Wall -o myprog myprog.c
1>    myprog.c: In function ‘main’:
1>    myprog.c:5:12: error: unknown type name ‘hahaha’
1>      int a = 0;hahaha
1>                ^~~~~~
1>    myprog.c:6:9: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before string constant
1>      printf("Hello Linux!\n");
1>             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1>    myprog.c:7:6: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘fun’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
1>      a = fun();
1>          ^~~
1>    myprog.c:5:6: warning: variable ‘a’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
1>      int a = 0;hahaha
1>          ^
1>    make: *** [Makefile:3: all] Error 1
1>    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Application Type\Linux\1.0\Linux.Makefile.Targets(322,5): error : make exited with code 2, please see the Output Window - Build output for more details (NOTE: the build output verbosity might need to be changed in Tools Options to see more information in the Output Window).
1>    Copying file '/home/abc/projects/Project2/myprog' to 'C:\Users\abc\source\repos\Project2\Project2\bin\x64\Debug\myprog'
1>  Done building target "_Build_Common" in project "Project2.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
1>Done building target "Build" in project "Project2.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
1>
1>Done building project "Project2.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>myprog.c(7,6): warning : implicit declaration of function ‘fun’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
1>myprog.c(5,6): warning : variable ‘a’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
1>myprog.c(5,12): error : unknown type name ‘hahaha’
1>myprog.c(6,9): error : expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before string constant
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Application Type\Linux\1.0\Linux.Makefile.Targets(322,5): error : make exited with code 2, please see the Output Window - Build output for more details (NOTE: the build output verbosity might need to be changed in Tools Options to see more information in the Output Window).
1>    2 Warning(s)
1>    3 Error(s)
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:02.72
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

EDIT:
Ok, I found that what matters is the code returned by the bash command (make).
It seems that if "make" returns 0, VS doesn't even parse the output, resulting in 0 Errors and 0 Warnings. If I force bash to return an error code like 127 (eg by setting the "Build Command Line" option in Project property page -> "Remote Build" to "make; blablabla" the output is correctly parsed but the compilation fails due to an unknown error and subsequently the debugging does not start.

[image: VS Error List screenshot]

Comment: Just use `-Werror`. You should anyway.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. thanks for the suggestion! Yes I know I should but I prefer having them differentiated if possible.

Comment: Seems pretty clear that Visual Studio doesn't parse GCC warnings. You can look for a plugin that might add that capability but other than that you're out of luck I suppose.  There's always Emacs! :)

Comment: @MadScientist Mmmm yes it could be... thanks for the suggestion. I edited the question adding some correctly parsed output... Emacs is always a valid alternative hahaha

Comment: @MadScientist Seems that Visual Studio doesn't parse GCC warnings only when bash return code is 0. I edited the question again. Suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, but I am not a Windows person and I don't use Visual Code either.  Seems like a silly restriction to me but... maybe there's some config option somewhere that controls this.  At least now you should have a more accurate way to search for answers.  In any event, this isn't a makefile question...

Comment: @MadScientist Don't worry thank you for your help, I really appreciate it :D